# If I have 45 buttons (numbers) and I have to choose 6 numbers, how can I make my 6 clicked buttons go to my 6 inputs numbers

Tags: javascript, html

If I have 45 buttons (numbers) and I have to choose 6 numbers, how can I make my 6 clicked buttons go to my 6 inputs numbers, that is I mean for each click on a button, send this value to an input type number

I clicked on the first button and I did the function of calling the input id = "chk1" to the first inbox innerHTML.value = "", but how do I make the second clicked button go to the second input?

21
   22

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         function botonear() {
          document.getElementById("chk1").value= 21;
         }
          function botonear2() {
          document.getElementById("chk2").value= 22;
         }
       </script>
```

I expect click in any button and send it to the first empty input, then second click in different button goes to the second empty input and so..

Comment: There is no PHP or MySQL in this question, please remove the tag!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `myButtons` and `myInputs` as arrays of your buttons and inputs respectively, you can:

1) use using `addEventListener` to attach event listeners to each button and detect clicks; and

2) use `array.prototype.find` to find your first empty input and update its value.

```
myButtons.forEach((button, i) =>
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      let firstEmptyInput = myInputs.find(input => !input.value);
      if (firstEmptyInput)
        firstEmptyInput.value = i;
    }));
```

[1] `addEventListener` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

[2] `find`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find`

Comment: Just another random question from a random user. Do you know what the deal is with `prototype`? I see it a lot and it looks messy. When new versions come out where the prototype is no longer used, will it become deprecated, causing havoc on half of the net? (Too early for this)

Comment: Using the keyword `prototype` in your code has become mostly obsolete since the (syntactical sugar) keyword `class` was introduced. But underneath, JS fundamentally uses `prototype` (as opposed to object-oriented classes in languages such as Java and C) for inheritance.